# Are there any detectors which implemented on GPU and are scale/rotate-invariant?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, feature-detection, feature-extraction, orb

As known in OpenCV 2.4.9.0 are these feature-detectors: `SIFT, SURF, BRISK, FREAK, STAR, FAST, ORB`.

- http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html
- http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html

All of these have implementation on CPU, but only `FAST` and `ORB` on GPU. http://docs.opencv.org/genindex.html

And as known, some are scale/rotate-invariant, but some aren't: [Are there any fast alternatives to SURF and SIFT for scale-invariant feature extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157806/are-there-any-fast-alternatives-to-surf-and-sift-for-scale-invariant-feature-ext)

These are scale-invariant and rotate-invariant:

- SIFT
- SURF
- BRISK
- FREAK
- STAR

But these are not scale-invariant and not rotate-invariant:

- FAST
- ORB

Are there any detectors which implemented on GPU and are scale/rotate-invariant?

Or will be added in OpenCV 3.0 on GPU or OpenCL?

Comment: Have you seen it (it already has OCL version)? http://docs.opencv.org/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html#gpu-surf-gpu

Comment: @Kornel Thank U! I have not seen this, missed. It is a pity that there are no FREAK/BRISK.

Comment: may be you can try AKAZE too. Also in 3.0, you needn't use ocl version of surf. It is in my default - see this link https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/xfeatures2d/src/surf.cpp#L895. Use `UMat` though.

Comment: @Kiran  Thank U. Yes, it seems to be the true - in OpenCV 3.0 SURF has 3 versions: CPU, CUDA and OCL(which trys to be used by default if can). And AKAZE seems to be more efficient than ORB: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/features2d/akaze_tracking/akaze_tracking.html But I didn't find anything about implementation AKAZE on GPU(OCL/CUDA).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, SURF is the only scale/rotate-invariant feature detector with GPU support in OpenCV.

In OpenCV 3.0 [FAST](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/src/fast.cpp#L333) and [ORB](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/src/orb.cpp#L962)have got OCL support and moreover, these two ([FAST](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/cudafeatures2d/include/opencv2/cudafeatures2d.hpp#L426) and [ORB](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/cudafeatures2d/include/opencv2/cudafeatures2d.hpp#L455)) have already got CUDA support.

The OCL/CUDA support of [SURF](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/xfeatures2d/src/surf.hpp) has been already mentioned in the comments of your question, but it is only a contribution to OpenCV and this is how OpenCV's developers about [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib):

> New modules quite often do not have stable API, and they are not
>   well-tested. Thus, they shouldn't be released as a part of official
>   OpenCV distribution, since the library maintains binary compatibility,
>   and tries to provide decent performance and stability.

Based on my previous experiences OpenCV’s implementation of SURF features were much weaker than [OpenSURF](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/xfeatures2d/src/surf.hpp). It would be reasonable to try it, or find some other open source implementations.

p.s.:
to my knowledge still there is no GPU accelerated version of [KAZE/AKAZE](https://github.com/pablofdezalc/akaze).

Answer (score 4):

I recently implemented AKAZE using CUDA with a couple of colleagues, if you are familiar with the original library you should have no problem using it since we respected the API. You can find the current version here:

https://github.com/nbergst/akaze